# Should I store data in on-heap memory or off-heap memory

Tags: ignite

I am wondering whether I should store data in on-heap memory or off-heap memory.
The official documentation states, "On-heap caching is useful in scenarios when you do a lot of cache reads on server nodes that work with cache entries in binary form or invoke cache entries' deserialization."

In my case, I persist data to MongoDB and store BSON binary data in cache.

1. Should I choose on-heap memory or off-heap memory?
2. What is the basis for the "-Xms10g -Xmx10g" in my JVM parameters? If the data is stored in off-heap memory, isn't 10G too large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not either-or. Ignite always stores its data off-heap.

In some specific circumstances, you can get better performance by *additionally* storing your data on the Java heap. Usually, it's not worth the extra memory.

As far as the heap size, roughly speaking, the space required is proportionate to the *use* of the data rather than the *volume*. My rule of thumb is 4Gb + 2Gb if you use SQL + 2Gb if you use persistence.